# External and internal user mounted storage devices permissions issue

Tags: permissions, users, usb-drive, fstab, ownership

When I'm trying to mount storage devices as a normal user (the well known double click as normal user to mount partitions and flash devices) I have this issue (there's another entry in this forum about this question):
**It mounts as root.**
The owner is root and the mounting permissions are set as read only for the rest of the users. I mean (read, execution, **755**).
This is annoying because **I have to change owner** of the /media/device to write it as root.
My laptop is not used only by me... My girlfriend and my sister use it and **they don't know about this things**...
The problem is that **as normal user, devices are mounted as root**...
I've realized that fstab also doesn't work nowadays. I thing it's because it was replaced for the normal userspace mount.
I'm running **ubuntu arzt (17.10) with kernel 4.13.15**
**EDIT:** I could say I've answered my question... I changed permissions of /media to full permissions for everyone and sticky bit,

```
chmod 1777 -R /media
```

It's not what I wanted. There should be another way to do this... Doing this that way gives full permissions to every user and group...

Comment: Typical file systems in external media are FAT32, NTFS, exFAT. This do not usually require fiddling. If EXT2/3/4 then yes, permissions (and mount points) need to be tweaked.

Comment: This problem is found with NTFS partitions... I still not solved it...
I updated ubuntu and the kernel. It never hapened to me with other versions of Ubuntu and even Debian.

Comment: Problem also for FAT... I have a flash USB disk (FAT)... It mounts as root

Comment: They do not usually... I know. It's an issue because of that.